# Test and Documentation in DBT Source.yml

Tags: testing, yaml, documentation, dbt

I am trying to add documentation (description: and columns: ) to my tables with tests on my primary key column.

After I run dbt compile, I keep getting an error on the description: line.  I've read all the documentation and have made sure my spacing is correct (as described by the documentation) yet I keep getting the error.

What else should I be looking for?

Comment: This is hard to answer without sharing your YAML file, could you perhaps edit your post to share that?  Or at least the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

These YAML typos can be very tricky and frustrating to diagnose! My advice for getting to root cause is to try:

1. commenting out as much as possible to get try and isolate where the issue is happening
2. a code editor that supports folding at the indentation -- better yet one that has YAML syntax highlighting and linting

the dbt docs has as [two sections on debugging invalid YAML](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/debugging-errors#compilation-errors) that are worth checking. there's basically three classes of errors:

1. indentation issues
2. missing values (e.g. `description:` with no value afterwards)
3. misspelled keys (e.g. `descirption: this col is useless`)